# Baldur's Gate 1 (GOG version) launches on one Ubuntu 14.04 machine but not the other (possibly wine related?)

Tags: wine

I run Ubuntu 14.04 on my main laptop (64bit version alongside Win7) and on my old laptop (32bit version replacing WinXP). I intalled Baldur's Gate 1 on both (downloaded off of the same GOG account) and they installed properly. Now, however, the old laptop manages to run the game in windowed mode (not full screen, though) while the new one cannot run it at all, even though I go through the exact same steps to run the games.
Here's the surprisingly different output I get depending on laptop and whether I use windowed mode:

**New Laptop windowed**

```
Running Baldur's Gate: The Original Saga windowed mode
[drunk][22/06/2016_14:33:42] WINEDEBUG=trace+x11settings
[drunk][22/06/2016_14:33:42] WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mscoree,mshtml=
[drunk][22/06/2016_14:33:42] WINEPREFIX=/home/elmar/Games/Baldurs Gate/drunk/../prefix/
[drunk][22/06/2016_14:33:42] starting wine in virtual desktop mode
[drunk][22/06/2016_14:33:43] wine run ended
```

And that's it, the terminal displays a new input line, awaits my next command and nothing happens.

**New Laptop full screen**

```
Running Baldur's Gate: The Original Saga
[drunk][22/06/2016_15:03:30] WINEDEBUG=trace+x11settings
[drunk][22/06/2016_15:03:30] WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mscoree,mshtml=
[drunk][22/06/2016_15:03:30] WINEPREFIX=/home/elmar/Games/Baldurs Gate/drunk/../prefix/
[drunk][22/06/2016_15:03:30] starting wine
[drunk][22/06/2016_15:03:30] starting drunk daemon
[drunkd][22/06/2016_15:03:30] preparing to start drunkd
[drunk][22/06/2016_15:03:31] wine run ended
elmar@elmar-RC530-RC730:~$ [drunkd][22/06/2016_15:03:31] primary display device detected as: LVDS1
[drunkd][22/06/2016_15:03:31] current resolution stored: 1366x768
[drunk][22/06/2016_15:03:31] waiting for BGMain2.exe to start
[drunkd][22/06/2016_15:06:42] BGMain2.exe failed to start
[drunkd][22/06/2016_15:06:42] nothing to observe. closing
```

Notice the 3 minute gap between the 2nd and 3rd to last lines. After that, it just seems to linger - 30 minutes later it still has not marked the next line as a new input line (however, typing *exit* does exit terminal, so it does not crash or anything).

**Old laptop windowed**

```
Running Baldur's Gate: The Original Saga windowed mode 
WINEPREFIX=/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/prefix 
GOG 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/wine_standalone/lib/:/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/wine_standalone/lib/i386-linux-gnu 
WINEDLLPATH=/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/wine_standalone/lib/wine 
WINEDEBUG=+xrandr 
WINELOADER=/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/wine_standalone/bin/wine 
WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mscoree,mshtml= 
Starting Wine with virtual desktop.
```

And then, after a little while, a bunch more lines and the game starts *(I guess these might be irrelevant to the problem at hand but just to be sure:)*

```
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_get_current_mode CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
fixme:d3d:wined3d_guess_card No card selector available for card vendor 0000 (using GL_RENDERER "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)"). 
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33aff8,0x00000000), stub! 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
fixme:dplay:dplobby_destroy Should kill the msg thread 
fixme:d3d_surface:wined3d_surface_flip Ignoring flags 0x1.
```

**Old Laptop full screen**

```
Running Baldur's Gate: The Original Saga fullscreen 
WINEPREFIX=/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/prefix 
GOG 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default 
xrandr: unrecognized option 'connected' 
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information. 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/wine_standalone/lib/:/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/wine_standalone/lib/i386-linux-gnu 
WINEDLLPATH=/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/wine_standalone/lib/wine 
WINEDEBUG=+xrandr 
WINELOADER=/home/elmar/Spiele/Baldurs Gate/wine_standalone/bin/wine 
WINEDLLOVERRIDES=mscoree,mshtml= 
Starting Wine. 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_get_current_mode CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:X11DRV_XRandR_Init Found XRandR 1.4. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes OUTPUT 0: name "default". 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_init_modes Adding mode 0x17e: 1024x768@76. 
fixme:d3d:wined3d_guess_card No card selector available for card vendor 0000 (using GL_RENDERER "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)"). 
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33aff8,0x00000000), stub! 
trace:xrandr:xrandr12_get_current_mode CRTC 0: mode 0x17e, 1024x768+0+0. 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default 
Restoring resolution. 
xrandr: unrecognized option 'connected' 
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
```

I would be more than glad if you could enlighten me as to the reason for what seems to me to be wildly erratic behaviour and possibly even suggest solutions, particularly to the new laptop's refusal to do anything at all (I am not overly surprised the old one has problems with graphics but I seriously don't understand what the new one is even doing wrong). Please know that I am relatively new to Linux and still learning how to do things around here, so please consider this when phrasing your answers. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the official guide? [Baldur's Gate Linux](http://wiki.dotslashplay.it/en/games/baldurs-gate)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And also provided some further insight into how this system actually works. Very helpful!